# Update several Columns in one Hibernate Query?

Tags: hibernate, nhibernate, hql

i have the Following HQL:

```
String hql = "UPDATE Buchung as b " +
             "set STORNO = :Storno " +
             "where ID = :BuchungID";
```

Is it possible to Update more then one column in a HQL? For Example:

```
String hql = "UPDATE Buchung as b " +
              "set STORNO = :Storno " +
              "set NAME = :Name " +
               ......  
              "where ID = :BuchungID";
```

I know how to do that in MSSQL but i dont know how to do that in Hibernate.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

HQL is no different than SQL in this case. Just use comma to separate columns:

```
String hql = "UPDATE Buchung as b set " +
          "STORNO = :Storno," +
          "NAME = :Name " +
           ......  
          "where ID = :BuchungID";
```

Answer (score 3):

The syntax is similar to the SQL syntax, but with mapped fields/properties instead of columns:

```
update Buchung set storNo = :storno, name = :name where id = :buchungID
```

Note that if the goal is to modify a single entity instance, you'd better do

```
Buchung b = (Buchung) session.get(Buchung.class, buchungId);
b.setStorNo(newStorno);
b.setName(newName);
```

Comment: @JB Nizet what to do for this case `update employee set empName= :empname, address = :address where dept = :dept`. where I did not update based on id.

Comment: Then an update query is more efficient. You could sill load all the matching entities using a select query, and update them in a loop, though. Beware that a direct update query bypasses the first-level cache.

Answer (score 1):

```
    String hql = "UPDATE Buchung as b set " +
          "STORNO = :Storno," +
          "NAME = :Name " +
           ......  
          "where ID = :BuchungID";

Query qr = session.createSQLQuery(hql);

qr.setParameter("Storno","sto_value");

qr.setParameter("Name","name_value");

...

qr.executeUpdate();
```

in normal, you must have "transaction" to run query

```
    Transaction transaction = null;
transaction = session.begintransaction();
...
transaction.commit();
```